# Jquery mouseenter event hangs if fired on pageload

Tags: jquery, freeze, mouseenter

I use jqueries mouseenter/mouseleave functions on some elements.

On Mouseenter some content gets loaded over ajax and add a menu to the elemet. On mouseleave the menu disappears.

If I hover the elements while the page is rendering the menus sometimes don't disappear. They stay visible. I can't reproduce this with a demo code.

Any suggestions? Could be a problem with .data()?

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '._hoverflow', channels.smallMenu );
$(document).on('mouseleave', '._hoverflow', channels.smallMenu );

toggleMenu: function(p,i){
    if( p.data('loaded') === true  ){
        if( p.data('visible') === true ){ 
            i.stop(true,true).fadeOut('fast'); 
            p.removeClass('fadet').data('visible',false);  
        } 
        else{ 
            i.stop(true,true).fadeIn('fast'); 
            p.addClass('fadet').data('visible',true);   
        }
        return true; 
    } return false;
},
smallMenu: function(a){
    var p = $(this), cid = parseFloat( p.data('id') ), i = p.find('.channel-dropdown');
    if( channels.toggleMenu(p,i) ){ return false; }
    p.addClass('fadet').data('loaded',true).data('visible',true);
    var s = $.post( channels.vars.details, { id: cid } );
    s.done(function(data){ channels.menuTemplate( data, cid ).appendTo(p).stop(true,true).fadeIn('fast'); });

},
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that after you have set `p.data('loaded', true)` you can't toggle the visible state because of your `p.data('loaded') === true` check in `toggleMenu`.

Move the logic around so you can always toggle the visibility but only load the content once:

```
toggleMenu: function(p,i){
    if( p.data('visible') === true ){ 
        i.stop(true,true).fadeOut('fast'); 
        p.removeClass('fadet').data('visible',false);  
    } 
    else{ 
        i.stop(true,true).fadeIn('fast'); 
        p.addClass('fadet').data('visible',true);   
    }
},

smallMenu: function(a){
    var p = $(this), cid = parseFloat( p.data('id') ), i = p.find('.channel-dropdown');

    // Always toggle the menu visibility.
    channels.toggleMenu(p,i);

    // But only load the content once.
    if( p.data('loaded') === true ){ return false; }
    p.addClass('fadet').data('loaded',true).data('visible',true);
    var s = $.post( channels.vars.details, { id: cid } );
    s.done(function(data){ channels.menuTemplate( data, cid ).appendTo(p).stop(true,true).fadeIn('fast'); });
}
```

Comment: the content is loaded only once, but your code is cleaner. Error still occurs. Some things work. The add/removeClass('fadet') works. The fadeIn(),fadeOut() stuff don't. The page loads, runs much JS and while doing this some of the elements hovered keep the menu visible and sometimes the hover effect is inverse, hide on hover show on leave...

Comment: ok. I think I got it. The stuff is loaded, this takes some time and the fadeIn is called after loading. This has nothing todo with the pageload. it fades the menu in after loading. No matter if hovered or not..

Comment: In this line:     s.done(function(data){ channels.menuTemplate( data, cid ).appendTo(p).stop(true,true).fadeIn('fast'); });
I need to check if the container has the class fadet. If not don't fade in.

Comment: Converted it to a pure css solution. Reduced the JS about 60%.